# Mysql connector python error violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2483)

Tags: python, mysql

Im running an application running React, python and MySQL with a docker compose, When I run the application everything works fine, but when a pettition to the database (from the frontend with axios) is made multiple times, the connection breaks and the following error appears. Everything is running locally

```
"2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'database:3306', system error: 8 EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2483)"
```

Here is the configuration of my connection and my dockerfile

```
    import mysql.connector


    return mysql.connector.connect(
    host=os.environ.get("database"),
    user="root",
    password="root",
    database="locatec",
    port=3306,
    auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
    )
```

```
  database:
      image: mysql
      container_name: database
      restart: always
      ports:
        - '3306:3306'
      #command: --init-file /init.sql
      volumes:
        - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
        - ~/apps/mysql:/var/lib/locatec5
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_USER: test
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
        MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
        TIMEZONE: UTC

      networks:
        - locatec

  server:
    build: 
      context: ../../../
      dockerfile: infra/deploy/backend/dev/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    container_name: server
    networks:
      - locatec
    depends_on:
      - database
```

I tried using

```
mysql-connector-python==8.0.30
```

, also I configured the param of ssl to false

Comment: Could try 8.0.31, but its [release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-python/en/news-8-0-31.html) don't list a fix. So this looks like a [bug](https://bug.mysql.com) that would be beneficial to report.

Comment: Is the server container crashing that caused the this? The `/var/lib/locatec5` looks odd and no `/var/lib/mysql` mount point.

Comment: Nothing looks crashed on docker, only the message appears and all connections are lost

Comment: If everything is running locally, why does it need SSL?

Comment: Nothing is using SSL, the only thing that requires  SSL is Auth0 that we are using on the frontend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an error I faced some time ago. In my case, it was due to a client initiating a secured connection to a non-secured server.

The error message indicates that the client has initiated a SSL/TLS connection and is expecting to receive more data than the server has sent during the handshake procedure.

There are two ways to fix this, either by:

- enabling SSL/TLS on server side so that the client can initiate a SSL/TLS handshake and get a consistent response. [Docker side]
- disabling the SSL/TLS from the database connector. [Python side]